# How to set the react select as the one in the image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

This is my page form which I'm working on [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGnwt.png) . I want to be same as this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBEcR.png)

,but I dont know how to set the multi select [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f17kU.png)

This is my code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <form className="container">
      <h4>General</h4>

      <div className="name block">
        <label htmlFor="frm-name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="frm-name"
          type="name"
          name="name"
          placeholder='Active input text'
          autoComplete="name"
          required
        />
      </div>

      <div className="context block">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-access">Access</label>
          <select 
            name="access" 
            id="frm-access" 
            type="text"
            autoComplete="given-access"
            >
            <option value="public">Public</option>
            <option value="private">Private</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-last">Purpose</label>
          <select 
            name="access" 
            id="frm-access" 
            type="text"
            autoComplete="given-access"
            >
            <option value="public">Support Agent</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="context block">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-mode">Mode</label>
          <select 
            name="access" 
            id="frm-access" 
            type="text"
            autoComplete="given-access"
            >
            <option value="public">Chat</option>
          </select>

        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-reference">Reference</label>
          <select 
            name="access" 
            id="frm-access" 
            type="text"
            >
            <option value="public">Include as link</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="context block">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-limit">Limit chat to x messages</label>
          <input
            id="frm-limit"
            type="text"
            name="limit"
            placeholder='10'
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frm-context">Context size</label>
          <select 
            name="context" 
            id="frm-context" 
            type="text"
           >
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option valu="large">Large</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="block sources">
        <label htmlFor="frm-sources">Sources</label>
        <select 
          
          name="sources" 
          id="frm-source" 
          type="text"
          isMulti
          >
          <option value="source1">Source1</option>
          <option value="source2">Source2</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div className="button block">
        <button type="save">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

globals.css

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  background: #e7e4e4ca;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(5, 4, 2);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.context {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 105%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 54px 55px rgb(78 78 78 / 25%), 0 -12px 30px rgb(78 78 78 / 25%),
    0 4px 6px rgba(31, 30, 30, 0.25), 0 12px 13px rgb(78 78 78 / 25%),
    0 -3px 5px rgb(78 78 78 / 25%);
}

.container input {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  border-color: rgb(221, 218, 218);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.container select {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  border-color: rgb(237, 221, 221);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #9e9fa3
}

.context div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

I checked react select docs and I added in select isMulti, but still is not working.
Does anybody can give me some hints?

Comment: The multiselect element you see in the image is a custom component.
Example you can use is: https://react-select.com/home

Comment: I followed the react select docs and I tried to implement a custom component Multi, but I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window." I understand that I didn't import useState, but it's imported. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: This is my code for custom component:                                                                           
 ``` <div className="block sources"> 
        <label htmlFor="frm-sources">Sources</label>
       <Select defaultValue={[colourOptions[1], colourOptions[2]]} isMulti name="colors" options={colourOptions} className="basic-multi-select" classNamePrefix="select"
        />                                                                                                                        </div> ```  , but it's not working and I get an error